# Restart JS script after TimeoutError

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, timeout, forever

I´m fetching some data from a website and need to go over a lot of pages - sometimes he does not find the selector and after some time - TimeoutError and the program stops.

I would like to automatically restart the program, when it runs into that Error or any error.

I tryed forever, but it just restart if i manually close the program after it has the error...

Comment: give your code sample. Are you using puppeteer?

Comment: Yes puppeteer! for example: const FOLLOW_SELECTOR = 'body > div:nth-child(12) > div > div.zZYga > div > article > header > div.o-MQd > div.PQo_0 > div.bY2yH > button';

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is one I'd solve with multiple attempts. Implement the OnError callback and recursively call the method again with the selector that could not be found.

To avoid having an infinite loop you can add a counter and break out of the loop as soon as it reaches a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using puppeteer and assuming you follow the `async/await` structure as shown in docs, you can enclose the .waitFor / selector inside a  function in a `try catch` block and on catch, call the function again. You could also use a global variable to limit the number of retries.